# Show that the function $f(z)=\frac{1-\cos z}{z^n}$ has no anti-derivative on $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ if $n$ is an odd integer.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

Show that the function $f(z)=\frac{1-\cos z}{z^n}$ has no anti-derivative on $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ if $n$ is a positive odd integer.

I think, If we can able to prove $\int_S f(z) dz \neq 0$, on the unit circle $S$, then by fundamental theorem of algebra gives the desired one. But, how can I use the definition $\int_\gamma f(z)dz=\int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt$ for a continuous function $f(z)$ on a piecewise smooth contour $\gamma:=\gamma(t),~a \leq \gamma \leq b$ ?

Comment: You can use the Cauchy's formula (if you are allowed to use it) to compute this integral. Namely, $f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{S}\frac{f(z)dz}{(z-a)^{n+1}}$ for $f$ holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's integral formula? If so, you can use it to directly calculate the integral. Otherwise, take the Taylor series of the cosine and use that to calculate the integral.

Comment: The Taylor series converges uniformly on the  unit circle and term by term integration gives the exact value of the integral.

Comment: What has the fundamental theorem of algebra to do with this?

Comment: $f(z)$ has an antiderivative if $n=1$. Do you restrict yourself to the case of $n=3,5,7,\dots$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, Am I confusing myself? When $n=1$, $f$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$ and hence extends to an entire function. This is more easily seen from $$f(z)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2k)!}z^{2k-1}.$$ Its antiderivative is then given by $$F(z)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2k)!(2k-1)}z^{2k}$$

Comment: @SangchulLee Sorry, don't know what I was thinking

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, No worries, I also make this kind of mistakes when my caffeine level drops low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(z)=1-\cos z$. Then\begin{align}\int_Sf(z)\,\mathrm dz&=\int_S\frac{g(z)}{z^n}\,\mathrm dz\\&=2\pi i\frac{g^{(n-1)}(0)}{(n-1)!}\end{align}which is $0$ if and only if $n$ is even.